# Limit the search to only one content type

Tags: nodes, search

I'm trying to setup a search for only one content type; I've tried to google it and I saw so many stuff that I don't know which one to test and as I don't want to install too many modules just to test things. I'm not actually even sure that I have to install something else to achieve that.

Do you have any hint or best implementation example please?

Comment: This can be easily done if you are using the Search Api Solr module.

Answer (score 1):

[These instructions](http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-filtering-solr-results) by [selvam](http://knackforge.com/selvam) on [KnackForge](http://knackforge.com) worked for me. Basically, you can use the `MODULE_search_apachesolr_query_prepare` hook to add a filter to the query before it's run.

```
<?php
function MODULE_search_apachesolr_query_prepare($query) {
  if (/* not correct page */)
    return;
  $compiled_filter = new SolrFilterSubQuery('AND');
  $compiled_filter->addFilter('bundle', 'TARGET_CONTENT_TYPE');
  $query->addFilterSubQuery($compiled_filter);
}
```

I haven't actually tried the hook, but I did use the filter and apply it to a query in a different context (API) and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your SOLR server is up and running and connected you can simply uncheck the content types you wish to exclude in the /admin/config/search/apachesolr under the configuration fieldgroup.  If you are looking to exclude specific nodes for some reason look at the Apache Solr Exclude Node

Comment: Well actually I have in pages a specific search box for only the content type shown in the page, so I don't want to uncheck all content types from the admin page.
But I'm gonna have a look at exclude node even if it would be easier to allow nodes than exclude ALL the others (many content type on this site)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment on @chadpeppers answer you might find it useful to use [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi), it allows you to narrow down your search by content type.

You could probably then write a custom module to provide a block that shows on each content type with a particular facet shown, and you wouldn't have to create separate indexes for all of your content types.